# Why is 0.99px border not showing in IE (fixed-data-table-2 issue)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-transforms, fixed-data-table

http://schrodinger.github.io/fixed-data-table-2/example-styling.html

In the table displayed on this dataTable demo page:

1 - try adding `1px black solid` border-bottom on `.public_fixedDataTableRow_main` element (it's basically a row of the table); **you'll be able to see the border.**

2 - now make the border-width `0.99px`, i.e. `.99px black solid`, **the border won't be displayed.**

And this happens *only in IE*! Works fine in Chrome, Safari and Edge.

P.S. while debugging, I reached to the point where removing CSS `transform` property from `.fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup` el, (a child of the row element itself) made the border appear (`.99px`) within that cell's bottom.

Edit: when using border-width .99px, the border **is there**, it is simply displayed *under* the div's children (even though `overflow:hidden` and `box-sizing:border-box` is given). Now as soon as it is made `1px`, it recognises the overflowing children and hides that much part of it so that the border is then visible.

Comment: 1px is the smallest unit you can have. If you provide invalid number the browsers try to do their best to apply what you want. If you want smaller this trick might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891177/css-border-less-than-1px

Comment: I know that, the issue here is, IE does display .99px border-widths in general, and here also it does display the border, but it is overriden by its children, but if the border-width is given `1px`, its not overriden by its children and the border is visible.