# What is the state of fractional px (like border-width) in HTML/CSS 2017?

Tags: html, css

related: [HTML: Sub-pixel border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709698/html-sub-pixel-border/30577685#30577685)

I tried to find something official [www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#px), but could not find a statement about a half pixel.

I read that some browsers do support, but what is the official state?

I remember long time ago, it was a "no no" and somehow nonsense, but time has changed. Even the pixel is not was it was before ...

Where to use? HD Display / printing

Comment: Also, duplicate of [Can a CSS pixel be a fraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9080633/215552)